# Sudden Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in "Category.tpl"

Tags: php

I cannot recall making any changes to my website and this error appeared out of the blue. I suspected the affiliates extension I installed after I encountered many spam affiliate sign ups. However, the issue persisted even after I disabled that extension.

The error when I clicked on the Categories on the homepage is:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in xxx/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl on line 140

Line 140 is the end.

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
<?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
<?php } ?>
<div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
  <h2><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h2>
  <?php if ($thumb || $description) { ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($description) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-10"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($categories) { ?>
  <h3><?php echo $text_refine; ?></h3>
  <?php if (count($categories) <= 5) { ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach (array_chunk($categories, ceil(count($categories) / 4)) as $categories) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
      <label class="control-label" for="input-sort"><?php echo $text_sort; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
      <select id="input-sort" class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
        <?php foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { ?>
        <?php if ($sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' . $order) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 text-right">
      <label class="control-label" for="input-limit"><?php echo $text_limit; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
      <select id="input-limit" class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
        <?php foreach ($limits as $limits) { ?>
        <?php if ($limits['value'] == $limit) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $limits['text']; ?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>"><?php echo $limits['text']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">
      <div class="product-thumb">
        <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
        <div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
            <p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
            <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
            <div class="rating">
              <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
              <?php if ($product['rating'] < $i) { ?>
              <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
            <p class="price">
              <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
              <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
              <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>
            </p>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="button-group">
            <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"><?php echo $results; ?></div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if (!$categories && !$products) { ?>
  <p><?php echo $text_empty; ?></p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $continue; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $button_continue; ?></a></div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
<?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Will someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a closing braket } opened in line 29

```
  <?php if ($categories) { ?>
```

as i dont know what your skript does and where it has to be closed...

at least last line

```
<?php } echo $footer; ?>
```

fixes the parser error

Comment: Hi Freddy! The links are now not broken but the products in the categories don't show. What else should I fix?

Comment: @Stella your code is hard to read... maybe you need to close the braket somewhere else

Comment: Hi Freddy! I couldn't find another bracket to close.